# Docker does not start on Windows Server

Tags: windows, docker, server, docker-desktop, windows-server-2022

I installed Docker on a Windows Server 2022 and it won't boot up.
[Docker Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHAgl.png)

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException:
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: n. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   bei Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-22253\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:Zeile 58.
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-22253\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:Zeile 29.
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-22253\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:Zeile 79.
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-22253\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:Zeile 108.
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-22253\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:Zeile 97.
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Docker.Engines.Engines.<StartAsync>d__24.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-22253\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:Zeile 124.
```

Thanks in advince.

Tried to re-install docker, enabled the Containers Feature.
At the docker installation I choose wsl 2 and not hyper-v. Because it is recommended in the docker installer.

Comment: can share the json. i think it's a invalid json